# combinations of elements in a set without symmetrical repetition

Tags: algorithm, set, combinatorics

I'm looking for an algorithm that works for any set size, for example in `{A B C}` I would like the following combinations:

```
ABC (== CBA)
ACB (== BCA)
BAC (== CAB)
```

**[EDIT]** I think something like the [gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) which generates the next permutation (p+1) by inverting only 2 elements in the current permutation (p) might help but I can't see the pattern yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are guaranteed that elements in the set are different and also assuming that they are comparable, the algorithm should be like following:

```
1) Go through all permutations
2) For each permutation take it if and only if its first element is less than
   the last one.
```

The second step allows exactly one permutation from each pair

Comment: I would have been more interested in a way to generate only the permutations that don't repeat rather than a filter function but since you provided a valid answer to the question I accepted it. I should have put it differently I guess :)

Comment: Ok, then based on the same idea you can do something like this: take all possible pairs from the set, for each pair generate all permutations of the rest n-2 elements, and for each generated permutation take the first element of the pair, then permutation of n-2 elements, and then the rest element of a pair

Comment: Just to clarify one thing about @maggot092's comment: "all possible pairs" should be just those pairs in which the first number is smaller than the second. But even the original filtering approach only takes at most twice as long as this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this could be homework, so here is just a hint.

Look at each of those pairs of combinations.

1. For any such "matched pair", we want to keep one of the combinations and throw the other away.  If you were given a single "matched pair" of combinations, is there any operation you could perform on them to decide which one of the two to keep?
2. Given one half of a pair, can you compute the other?

Comment: Ha no this is self-inflicted :) 1) doesn't matter which one we keep 2) yes, just revert the order (symmetry)

Comment: The idea behind (1) is that if you have a consistent (but otherwise totally arbitrary) rule for picking one "canonical" item from each pair, then you can just generate all items, and check each item x by computing its "partner" y and seeing which of the two is canonical: if it's x, output it, otherwise don't.  maggot092's "first char < last char" is an example of such a canonicity rule.